# Javascript document.cookie remove "name" and "value"

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

In my Javascript I have a cookie with several names and values:

```
"Token=23432112233299; sessionuid=abce32343234"
```

From server when I download a file a Add a Cookie so the new document cookie will look:

```
  "Token=23432112233299; sessionuid=abce32343234; fileDownload=true"
```

How can I remove the `fileDownload` name and value from `cookie` and update document.cookie?

**UPDATE:**

This is the code I have done so far but its not working:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("fileDownload=true;") != -1) {
    document.cookie = document.cookie.replace("fileDownload=true;", "");
} else {
    document.cookie = document.cookie.replace("fileDownload=true", "");
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far to manipulate cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Change the expires parameter to the elapsed date.
document.cookie = 'fileDownload = ; expires=-1';

Answer (score 0):

```
    var cookieData = "fileDownload=; path=/" +"; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString() + ";";
    if (null) cookieData += " domain=null;";
    document.cookie = cookieData;
```